# what does the "()" do within an rank statement

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Just curious what the "()"'s do in "rank ()" statements and how I can apply them.

for example the following is a standard rank query but I have never populated "()" just the brackets after "OVER" keyword and am curious what it's purpose is?

```
SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col1 DESC)
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Check the doc [RANK](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions155.htm#SQLRF00690)

Comment: Doesn't explain the question I am posing very well

Comment: @jackd102 - You may wish to approach your statements from a different perspective.  You could say "I don't understand the documentation well enough to apply it to my question".  But your current assertion also implies that ***_I_*** wouldn't be able to answer your question reading that documentation.  As a guiding principle in life, assume you're mistaken or you don't understand, before asserting that the world around you is mistaken or deficient...

Comment: The docs show they are a required part of the syntax for the analytic version, and nothing goes in between. The ["see also" link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#i81407) from that page also shows the general syntax with `arguments` being optional - "Analytic functions take 0 to 3 arguments".

Comment: The brackets are part of syntax and are required. And you don't have to populate them if you're using it as an analytic function. Having said that, it does seem to accept one or more arguments in which case it behaves differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RANK()` is a function that takes no arguments.

Calling a function (generally) requires the parentheses.  They simply indicate that it is a function call.  In this case, the function requires the rest of the window frame, so `OVER` is required.